# I'm getting Author_Name out of line in post-byline

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I'm working with my wordpress magazine website designing. I'm setting posts where, below the title, I need **"By Author_Name | Last Updated Modified_Date"**. With `$post_author = get_the_author();`, I got the desired thing but Author Name was just a simple text and not the profile link of Author. So, I tried `$post_author = the_author_posts_link();`. With this, I got **"[Author_Name](http://#) By | Last Updated Modified_Date"** instead of getting **"By [Author_Name](http://#) | Last Updated Modified_Date"**. Below is the code which I placed in function.php of wordpress theme and then the output. Please help me fixing. Thanks in Advance!

What I coded in function.php:

```
if ( $author == 'no' && $date == 'no' ) {
    return;
}

$post_author = the_author_posts_link();
// add compatibility when used in header before loop
if ( empty( $post_author ) ) {
    global $post;
    $post_author = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );
}
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time(‘U’);
$post_date = date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( get_the_date('r') ) ); 
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');

echo '<div class="post-byline">';
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 120) {
// translators: %1$s = the author who published the post. %2$s = the date it was modified
printf( esc_html_x( 'By %1$s | Last Updated on %3$s', 'This blog post was published by some author on some date ', 'mission-news' ), esc_html( $post_author ), esc_html( $post_date ), esc_html( $updated_date )) ;}
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

and what I got:

```
<div class="post-byline">
<a href="localhost/root/author" title="Posts by author" rel="author">Author</a>
By  | Last Updated on December 13th, 2018
</div>
```